# Drop column in Dynamo DB table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I've been looking through the AWS Dynamo DB documentation and the Amazon Dynamo interface and it seems like there's no way to remove a column from a table, outside of deleting the entire table with it's contents and starting over, is that true?

If so, why would Amazon not support this?

Comment: Except for the required primary key, a DynamoDB table is schema-less. What does "removing a column" mean in this context?

Comment: If you browse items in a table in the interface for example, there are columns (attributes) of the table there.  In fact, there's a button at the top right with a label saying "Show or Hide attributes (columns) from the Browse Items view"

Comment: Ah, I understand what you are saying now. It seems more like it is done as a handy UI tool to be able to see the individual attributes. The only way to do this would be to perform a `Scan` with a [`FilterExpression`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#DDB-Scan-request-FilterExpression) that includes the [`attribute_exists(attribute_name)`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.SpecifyingConditions.html#ConditionExpressionReference) to filter on, and then then request to update the item and remove that attribute.

Comment: Gotcha.  Yeah, I pretty much expect things to be different in dynamo land but their interface kind of conveys it should be possible in a SQL sort of way :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Try **removing all data from that column, it will automatically remove that column**.

Comment: This worked in AWS explorer. (although you need to close the table and reopen it to see the change.)

Answer (score 9):

Using document client with javascript, we can do this:

```
const paramsUpdate = {
       TableName: tableName,
       Key: { HashKey: 'hashKey' },
       UpdateExpression: 'remove #c ',
       ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#c': 'columnName' }
};
documentClient.update(paramsUpdate, (errUpdate) => {
       if (errUpdate) log.error(errUpdate);
});
```

In here we set *UpdateExpression* with **remove** sentence

Answer (score 7):

There is a [**`REMOVE`**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Modifying.html#Expressions.Modifying.UpdateExpressions.REMOVE) action in the DynamoDB API.

Answer (score 4):

DynamoDB does not have a schema definition, and so there is no such thing as a "column". It also means there is no way to delete all attributes with the same name without iterating over each record.

A solution I recommend is to keep these attributes, and to make your code refer to that same data using a fresh attribute name.

For example, attribute `content` could become `content_v2`. It might not look so clean, but it's cheap, quick and your old data would be backed up.

Answer (score 1):

Setting all instances of the column value to null clears the column.

In C#, this method does the trick using the persistence framework:

```
static void RemoveColumn()
{
    var myItems = context.ScanAsync<MyObjectType>(null).GetRemainingAsync().Result;

    // Foreach item, update
    myItems.ForEach(myObject =>
    {
        myObject.UnwantedColumn = null;
        context.Save(myObject);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all the data for that one column. On my end, it automatically refreshed, might have to refresh the page.